# Dynamic Gravity list in jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I need to populate a drop down list in a jsp page form using the values fetched from the database. The condition is only few rows are fetched from the database based on the other fields of the form. How do i do this without using jQuery or other stuff? I'm quite new to coding, so i require help.

The scenario is, based on employee id entered, the state of the employee has to fetched from the database. And then based on the state fetched from database i need to create a drop down list containing the different office branches present in that state from the database. I dont want multiple pages for taking these details, just one form in a page. How to i populate such a dropdown box in a jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have to go for jquery or AJAX which will populate your 
data without an actual servlet request, or you have to do this 
in two different forms.